# Creating test records for visualforce controller

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

So I have a visualforce page that I am currently trying to write test code for.  I have everything setup, and there really is not much to test in my custom controller other than some series of if statements on certain fields (mostly picklists) in my custom object.  Obviously, there are several options for all these picklists, so I was wondering is there any way to create records to be tested that have random field values (so that I could probably cover all my options if I just had a large list of records with random field values)?  I am hoping not to create records one by one so that every option in every picklist is covered (i.e. all my if statements get tested).

Comment: You can create a large number of records in a loop and use the iterator to help dynamically build the name.

Comment: you might want to post some of the if statements as, if they fall into a regualr pattern, through code restructure using maps, you can greatly simplify the test code

Comment: I suggest you avoid anything random (including using today's date) in tests. While with some random value you may discover a bug in the code being tested, it is a similar probability that you may be discovering a bug in your test. And that will be an unhappy experience if it is during a time-sensitive deployment window. So as the other comments suggest, loop over all permutations or otherwise get coverage through deterministic logic.

Comment: Thanks for your guys input.  How does this question get a minus point?  I just started my computer science major as well as salesforce development this past year.  It might seem stupid to others but it's a legitimate question.  I figured that your guys answer was the way to go before this.  I guess I was just curious if salesforce had anything standard for doing something like this.  Sheez.

Comment: @smitie Don't let random (and IMHO unjustified) minus points get you down. You'll probably pick up just as many random (and unjustified) positive points along the way...